# Laravel Lighthouse Problem with schema validation Undefined Scalar Mixed

Tags: laravel-lighthouse

I am trying to validate-schema but I am running into a very unfamiliar error. This happens when I try to run the PHP artisan lighthouse:validate-schema command.

Prior to this, I have not encountered this problem at all. In fact, I just did an install of this package yesterday and it was working then. take note that this is not a base lighthouse package and I do have schema defined

```
{
  "message": "No matching subclass of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\ScalarType of found for the scalar Mixed",
  "exception": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Exceptions\\DefinitionException",
  "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Schema/TypeRegistry.php",
  "line": 263,
  "trace": [
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Schema/TypeRegistry.php",
      "line": 194,
      "function": "resolveScalarType",
      "class": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\TypeRegistry",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Schema/TypeRegistry.php",
      "line": 176,
      "function": "resolveType",
      "class": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\TypeRegistry",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 130,
      "function": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\{closure}",
      "class": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\TypeRegistry",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 105,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Schema/TypeRegistry.php",
      "line": 177,
      "function": "then",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Schema/TypeRegistry.php",
      "line": 147,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\TypeRegistry",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Type/Schema.php",
      "line": 164,
      "function": "possibleTypes",
      "class": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\TypeRegistry",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Type/Schema.php",
      "line": 133,
      "function": "resolveAdditionalTypes",
      "class": "GraphQL\\Type\\Schema",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Schema/SchemaBuilder.php",
      "line": 91,
      "function": "__construct",
      "class": "GraphQL\\Type\\Schema",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/GraphQL.php",
      "line": 224,
      "function": "build",
      "class": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\SchemaBuilder",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/GraphQL.php",
      "line": 157,
      "function": "prepSchema",
      "class": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\GraphQL",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/GraphQL.php",
      "line": 110,
      "function": "executeQuery",
      "class": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\GraphQL",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Support/Http/Controllers/GraphQLController.php",
      "line": 70,
      "function": "executeRequest",
      "class": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\GraphQL",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "function": "query",
      "class": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Support\\Http\\Controllers\\GraphQLController",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php",
      "line": 54,
      "function": "call_user_func_array"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php",
      "line": 45,
      "function": "callAction",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
      "line": 219,
      "function": "dispatch",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
      "line": 176,
      "function": "runController",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
      "line": 681,
      "function": "run",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 130,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Support/Http/Middleware/AcceptJson.php",
      "line": 30,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 171,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Support\\Http\\Middleware\\AcceptJson",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 105,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
      "line": 683,
      "function": "then",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
      "line": 658,
      "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
      "line": 624,
      "function": "runRoute",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
      "line": 613,
      "function": "dispatchToRoute",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
      "line": 170,
      "function": "dispatch",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 130,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
      "line": 21,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 171,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
      "line": 21,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 171,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
      "line": 27,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 171,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
      "line": 63,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 171,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php",
      "line": 57,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 171,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/spatie/laravel-cors/src/Cors.php",
      "line": 41,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 171,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Spatie\\Cors\\Cors",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
      "line": 105,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
      "line": 145,
      "function": "then",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
      "line": 110,
      "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/Projects/snaptuity-api/public/index.php",
      "line": 55,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/richard/.config/composer/vendor/cpriego/valet-linux/server.php",
      "line": 232,
      "function": "require"
    }
  ]
}
```

here is the full stack trace.

it says `No matching subclass of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\ScalarType of finding for the scalar Mixed` however, I have verified that I do not ever declare any scalar type "mixed"

Answer (score 1):

After much digging i found out that the way i had installed my packages was all wrong.

mll-lab/graphql-php-scalars

was required by a certain package that we install. however for some reason it wasnt being downloaded at all into the vendor folder probably because of a messed up composer.lock file.

Comment: Apparently this problem will also occur if mll-lab/graphql-php-scalars is out of date. My composer.json did explicitly require the package, but upgrading from 3=>4 resolved the same problem. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Richard.